# Laravel 8 Fortify Redirect based on roles without jetstream

Tags: laravel, laravel-fortify

I am looking for a good tutorial or advice on how to redirect after authenticated based on roles in laravel 8 fortify without jetstream.  I have found one that says to create a new LoginResonse.php in App\Http\Responses\loginresponse.php which I did but I am not sure where to register this new response because the tutorial I am using says to do it in Jetstreamserviceprovider but I am not using Jetstream.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You will want to register your custom `LoginResponse` in the `FortifyServiceProvider`, specifically the `boot` method.

```php
public function boot()
{
    $this->app->singleton(
        \Laravel\Fortify\Contracts\LoginResponse::class,
        \App\Http\Responses\LoginResponse::class
    );
}
```

This registers your custom `LoginResponse` with Laravels IoC service container and informs Laravel to provide your `LoginResponse` to methods that require an instance of an object which implements the `LoginResponse` from `Fortify`.

Inside your custom `LoginResponse` and in the `toResponse` method, you can perform whatever logic you require. For example;

```php
public function toResponse($request)
{
    if ($request->wantsJson()) {
        return response()->json(['two_factor' => false]);
    }

    if (Auth::user()->hasRole('admin') {
        return redirect(route('admin.index'));
    }
}
```